# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 chart not showing all data points

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts

I'm creating a drill down report using a column chart to display data for a given day. Each column shows the max value in that hour of the day. When I click a column the same query is run in a line chart but the date range is changed to be for only that hour of data, passing through the field value of testDate as a parameter fromDate the date range looks like this: testDate >= fromDate AND testDate < DATEADD(HOUR, 1, fromDate). So only that hour of data is got.

My problem is that not all values within the hour are always displayed, most reports when clicked into show the whole hour: [Whole hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVDHM.png) but some of them show only the first 35 minutes and cut off before an expected very large number: [Cut off data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7mWs.png) In this case a value of 948 should occur at around 7:47 but just doesn't appear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I bumped it up to a 2 hour window which showed all of the data and it will do the job, but I'm still curious as to why it wasn't working before, here is an image of data from 07:00 to 09:00, [Two hour window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Fzi.png)

Comment: Do you want data for the hour prior to now, or the hour prior to this hour? Example, at 08:30 do you want 07:30 - 08:30 or 07:00 to 08:00?

Comment: The data for the hour I click into, so 07:00 to 08:00